# Complicated excel equation with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have a sheet that I use to calculate my taxes, deductions, and 401k based on a timesheet.  It also calculates my PTO, sick, and comp days (I don't get overtime, when I work overtime I get that time back at the end of the year as extra paid days off).  My issue is that with the timesheet, it's tough to calculate my sick days, all other times are hour for hour or based on the pay period.  But with sick days I get a specific amount every year.

Basically, I get 10 days (80 hours) per year.  So I take that 80 hours, divide it by 26, and that gives me how much sick time I get per pay period.  Problem is, since I get a biweekly pay, that's not actually correct.  So for example, this month I have 2 paychecks, I'd get .92 days of sick time, but I should actually get 1.  On the 2 months out of the year where I have 3 paychecks I would get 1.38 days of sick time, which of course isn't correct either.

So the issue is I'm trying to figure out how to write a formula to give me the the correct number of days.  Refer to the screenshot:

[image]

So basiclaly on G6, the formula takes the rolled over sick days from the previous year (G39) and adds the current sick time to it.  It decides that by checking if the gross pay for that pay period is there, then multiplies that amount by the sick time accrual rate (G40) and divides that by 8 to give me the days.

But what I want to do is to check how many months have been filled out and return that.  So in this example May has been completed, so it would return 1 day.  Since September has 3 pay periods, you will need to have all three September paychecks filled out for it to increment from 4 to 5 (may, jun, jul, aug makes 4).

Any ideas?  Everything I've tried to do this it just fails.  Keep in mind that those dates are dynamic, next year when I change the start date for the tax year, the months that have 3 months will change to match the actual pay periods for that year.  So this formula will need to actually be able to count that any month has 3 pay periods to advance the sick day count, otherwise to do it if there are only 2 that have been filled.

Comment: Do you get to take sick hours, or when you are sick it is the full day that is taken off?  Not that really matters just trying to get at are you really tracking days or hours.  And just to get a clearer understanding.  If on the second day at this job before you start work you got sick and were out of commission for the next two weeks you would not get paid any of your sick time?  or would you get paid, but would have nothing left for the rest of the year?

Comment: We can do hours, typically I'd take the entire day off though.  But there are times where I may have an appointment or something that I'll just take 2-3 hours and come in for work.

Comment: I know you descried accruing your sick benefit on a per pay period basis, but part of the reason I asked about that second day illness scenario, is that some companies are set up that at the start of the year you have your 80 hours available to you to use.  in which case, your sick day calc would simply be `=80-sum(L5:L30)` plus your carry over from previous years since you are allowed to do that.  not all companies do.  Also do you have a cap to the number of sick days you can accrue?  Some companies do not allow accruing of vacation, sick time, etc over a maximum value.

Comment: one thing that is not clear to me is how were planning on accruing your sick day by month.  80 hours is 10 sick days.  you described accruing 1 day per month, but there are 12 months to the year.  So a little more explination  this process might help too.

Comment: When I said 80 hours I mispoke, the 80 hours is for something else.  It's actually 96.  We simply get 1 sick day per month.  There's no need to worry about a maximum, our maximum's can be converted over to PTO or retirement, both of which I will set up separately.  We just get 1 day (8 hours) per month.

Comment: ok, and the indication that a period has been completed/entered is? `=sum(J5:O5)>0`

Comment: No, it's just if Column P is greater than 0, just like it is now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111364/discussion-between-forward-ed-and-flynn).

Comment: ^%*^@()&@ hit esc by accident and lost my entire answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt #2 to answer! >8(

The end equation to do this all in one cell is going to get ugly,but it will work.  In order to explain this and basically how I developed it, I am going to break it down into parts.  At the end the parts will be back substituted into the big equation.

The first thing I did was determine what row was last filled, or as per the comments what is the last row of column P that has a value greater than 0.  In order to determine this I used the aggregate function in a temporary cell of T15 (yes, in the middle of your spreadsheet but it wont matter in the end):

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,(P5:P30>0)*(ROW(P5:P30)-ROW(P5)+1),1)
```

To break this function down:

- 14 tells it we want to do an array type calculation sorting the array from largest to smallest.
- 6 tells it to ignore errors
- (P5:P30>0) tells it to build a true (or 1) and false (or 0) array of cells greater than 0
- (ROW(P5:P30)-ROW(P5)+1) generates an array listing row numbers
- 1 tells it to return the largest value in the array, if it was 2 the second largest.

Now the important thing here is what happens when you multiply the greater than 0 array with the row number array.  You wind up getting only the row numbers where there is a value in P greater than 0.  And when we sort that and ask for the largest number we get the last row you have completed.  Something to work with.

So now we can look up the last date completed, do some checks to see if its the end of the month or not and figure out how many sick days.  The ugly formula starts out as:

```
=IF(MONTH(INDEX(I5:I30,T15))=MONTH(INDEX(I5:I30,T15)+14),MONTH(INDEX(I5:I30,T15))-1,MONTH(INDEX(I5:I30,T15)))
```

The logic test here is to find our if the last filled out date and the date 14 days in the future are still the same month.  If they are the same month, you are not at the end of the month yet and there for have only earn up to the previous month's number in sick days.  As such this part will tell us the previous month's number os sick days:

```
MONTH(INDEX(I5:I30,T15))-1
```

Now if the date 14 days in the future is not the same month then we know the last entry for the month has been completed and therefore we have accrued that month's number in sick days and use basically the same formula:

```
MONTH(INDEX(I5:I30,T15))-1
```

well I can see we have called on cell T15 4 times just to determine if we are subtracting 1 or 0.  While the IF formula may feel more inline with your thought process, we can rearrange things and still get the same results but shortening the formula, reducing the calls to cell t15 by 1 and dropping the IF all together.  This only works because we are dealing with 1 and 0 which is also true and false.

```
=MONTH(INDEX(I5:I30,T15))-(MONTH(INDEX(I5:I30,T15))=MONTH(INDEX(I5:I30,T15)+14))
```

Now lets bypass that T15 calculation and back substitute it in to the month formula above to get:

```
=MONTH(INDEX(I5:I30,AGGREGATE(14,6,(P5:P30>0)*(ROW(P5:P30)-ROW(P5)+1),1)))-(MONTH(INDEX(I5:I30,AGGREGATE(14,6,(P5:P30>0)*(ROW(P5:P30)-ROW(P5)+1),1)))=MONTH(INDEX(I5:I30,AGGREGATE(14,6,(P5:P30>0)*(ROW(P5:P30)-ROW(P5)+1),1))+14))
```

Not done yet.  That only tells you the number of days you have accrued this year.  Not what you really want to know.  you need to convert it to hours. It also need to be reduced by the number of sick days used.  The following need to be added to the big ugly above:

- *8 for 8 sick hours to a sick day
- -sum($L$5:$L$30) to account for sick time used

this results in:

```
=(MONTH(INDEX(I5:I30,AGGREGATE(14,6,(P5:P30>0)*(ROW(P5:P30)-ROW(P5)+1),1)))-(MONTH(INDEX(I5:I30,AGGREGATE(14,6,(P5:P30>0)*(ROW(P5:P30)-ROW(P5)+1),1)))=MONTH(INDEX(I5:I30,AGGREGATE(14,6,(P5:P30>0)*(ROW(P5:P30)-ROW(P5)+1),1))+14)))*8-sum($L$5:$L$30)
```

Now I did notice during testing that if no entries are in the spreadsheet, then the row of the last entry become 0 and this is simply not acceptable as it causes some strange results.  So we will wrap this whole formula in a small error catcher to make sure 0 is the results when no payperiods have been completed.

```
=if(sum(P5:P30)=0,0,(MONTH(INDEX(I5:I30,AGGREGATE(14,6,(P5:P30>0)*(ROW(P5:P30)-ROW(P5)+1),1)))-(MONTH(INDEX(I5:I30,AGGREGATE(14,6,(P5:P30>0)*(ROW(P5:P30)-ROW(P5)+1),1)))=MONTH(INDEX(I5:I30,AGGREGATE(14,6,(P5:P30>0)*(ROW(P5:P30)-ROW(P5)+1),1))+14)))*8-sum($L$5:$L$30))
```

The icing on the cake is adding on the accrued sick days from the previous year.  Since I am not sure how the sick rate and sick start work together I will leave that calculation up to you and simply let you know that whatever number gets carried over from the previous year, simply add it to the above formula after the very last ).

Here is my test bed showing proof of concept:

[image: proof of concept]

WARNING:  This method ##WILL## produce false results for a pay period is =0 before the last date with a pay period >0  see example below:

[image: problem with method]

Comment: Yeah, when I use this with only 1 month filled out it says I have 40 sick days

Comment: @Flynn the first month or did you fillin one month sometimes after the first month.

Comment: @Flynn as per the warning at the very end of the answer, if you only fill out the time slots may and none of the time slots before it, it will give you a false number.  That is because the whole premise is that the last row that is filled out means all other rows up to the start of the year have been filled out as well.  So if you only fill out may, it still assumes that jan, feb, mar and april have also been filled out.

Comment: in order to find out the earliest entry we can reverse the process with the aggregate function and find the smallest enter value.  Then calculate the number of months up to that row and subtract those sick days.  This bring up some more questions though.  If you first entry for the year is part way through a month, so say you have hours for 17/04/16 and 17/04/30, do you get a sick day for that month since you did not work in the 17/04/02 period?

Comment: I just started working there, so there's no hours worked prior to last month

Comment: so when is the first sick day earned when you start mid month?  Do you just need to work in the last pay period for the month or 2 periods or all periods?

Comment: It doesn't matter, what I'm asking for is that when a full month is filled out (it'll always be either 2 or 3 pay periods) that the sick count increment by 1 day or 8 hours

Comment: it matters because the way you determine the a partial year is to subtract what has not been filled out yet from what has been filed out.   The difference is how many days you currently have in a partial year.

Comment: Except a partial year isn't the same as a 12 month period.  If you count partial years, you would end up with 13 months.  I need to find a way to get how many of a month is in the far left column, then check to make sure every month's row is filled out, then add a sick day because it is.

Comment: poor choice of phrasing on my part,  you need to subtract the incompleted months from the start of your 12 month period from the last fully completed month in the 12 month period.

Comment: So I added G39 to the formula and this worked.  So for this first year I just put in -4 as my carry over from last year since I didn't work the first 4 months and that solved everything.  Then next year I can put my actual carryover and it'll add last years to this year and it'll be fine.